# Access submodule from another submodule when both submodules are in the same main module

Tags: rust, module

I'm using `rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)` and I've got the following multi-file setup:

```
my_app/
+- my_lib/
|   +- foo
|   |   +- mod.rs
|   |   +- a.rs
|   |   +- b.rs
|   +- lib.rs
|   +- Cargo.toml
+- src/
|   +- main.rs
+- Cargo.toml
```

```ini
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies.my_lib]
path = "my_lib"
```

```
// src/main.rs
extern crate my_lib;

fn main() {
    my_lib::some_function();
}
```

```
// my_lib/lib.rs
pub mod foo;

fn some_function() {
    foo::do_something();
}
```

```
// my_lib/foo/mod.rs
pub mod a;
pub mod b;
 
pub fn do_something() {
    b::world();
}
```

```
// my_lib/foo/a.rs
pub fn hello() {
    println!("Hello world");
}
```

```
// my_lib/foo/b.rs
use a;
pub fn world() {
    a::hello();
}
```

When I try to compile it I get the following error thrown for the `use` statement in `B.rs`:

```
unresolved import `A`. There is no `A` in `???`
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `use` paths are *absolute, not relative*.  When you say `use A;` what you are actually saying is "use the symbol `A` in the root module of this crate", which would be `lib.rs`.

What you need to use is `use super::A;`, that or the full path: `use foo::A;`.

I wrote up a an article on [Rust's module system and how paths work](https://gist.github.com/DanielKeep/470f4e114d28cd0c8d43) that might help clear this up if the [Rust Book chapter on Crates and Modules](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html) doesn't.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the `B::world()` is indeed wrapped in an other function. I'm using cargo to compile the project. Could be a bug in cargo then?

Comment: If using Cargo is necessary to reproduce, please post your `Cargo.toml` file.  As it stands, the example as given compiles just fine.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for clarifying it. Is it idiomatic however to use `super::module_name`? It feels a bit awkward.

Comment: As of Rust 2018 Edition, `use` is now always relative (or an external crate) and its path doesn't start at the crate root (unless using `crate::...`). See the change in the [edition guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#use-paths).